# Circular imports and class fields in python3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-import

Okay, I do understand that this topic is old as hell, but I couldn't find an answer to the particular question that I am asking.

Let's say that we have a very simple structure: two files, `a.py` and `b.py`, their contents being:

`a.py`

```
import b

class C:
    lal = 4

class A:
    kek = 12
    lol = b.B()
```

`b.py`

```
import a

class B:
    aa = a.C()
```

Trying to run `python b.py`, we get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File ".../a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b
  File ".../b.py", line 3, in <module>
    class B:
  File ".../a.py", line 5, in A                                                                                  
    aa = a.C()
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'C'
```

**BUT** if we move the `import b` line **AFTER** the `C` class, the script launches and produces no errors.

I have not found any mention of this whatsoever in any answers here on SO.  The question here is: **Why** does this happen and ***how*** to escape this?

*This is a particularly important question for the Django framework. When I have many models, I try splitting them into many files. It is very easy to get a cyclic import there.*

Comment: I am not so educated in this field, but I believe the answer lies here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html . I also suggest to use "from module_x import class_y" instead of "import *". It can help a lot to avoid these kinds of hicups.

Comment: The module will exist in sys.modules before the loader executes the module code. This is crucial because the module code may (directly or indirectly) import itself; adding it to sys.modules beforehand prevents unbounded recursion in the worst case and multiple loading in the best.

Answer (score 1):

In python when you import a module then it first import all module that defines at the top of the module, If a module is not in sys.modules, then an import creates the new module entry in sys.modules and then executes the code in the module.

so when you try to import b.py module in a.py then it first import all module that listed in b.py is a.py (import a) if module not listed in sys.modules .  and still module b.py not completely executed so b.py module is not added into sys.modules

after that, it tries to import a.py and in a.py it tries first import all module that import in a.py is b.py

so it's a basic cycle  a.py try to import b.py and b.py try to import a.py

[image]

For that problem, Solution is import one module or class  inside the class, Not at the top of the module

as per your example

**a.py**

```
class C:
    lal = 4

class A:
    import b
    kek = 12
    lol = b.B()
```

**b.py**

```
import a

class B:
    aa = a.C()
```

or

**a.py**

```
import b
class C:
    lal = 4

class A:

    kek = 12
    lol = b.B()
```

**b.py**

```
class B:
    import a
    aa = a.C()
```

for detailed [information discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/HYChxtsrhnw)

[Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue992389)

Comment: As I indicated in my answer, I know this is a solution. But I don't get why. And it's probably a bad thing to do since all imports should be at the top of the file.

Comment: it's not actually true. If it was a cycle, then there would be a completely other error. Besides, your fix (which works, *as I indicated that I know*) would not actually fix that problem - it would still be cyclic.

Comment: @feakuru cycle import error dont give any other error it give same error as you show in your question

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Kallz already provided the right answer, but you are being bit stubborn :) You are creating circual reference which would end in infinite loop. Python has a mechanizm to avoid such loop by going line by line. 1st you open b.py - it gets loaded into the sys.modules as '__main__' and starts to be loaded. While loading it comes to 'import a'. So it looks for module 'a'. It finds it and puts it into the sys.modules. sys.modules now has '__main__' and 'a'. It starts to load module 'a' where it encounters 'import b'. So it finds 'b.py' and puts it into sys.modules. Now you have '__main__', 'a', 'b' and it starts to load 'b' where it encounters 'import a' - this time module 'a' is already in sys.modules and loading of it has already started! So Python knows something fishy is going on and you get yourself an ImportError.

Comment: as you might notice, I am not getting an `ImportError`. I am getting an `AttributeError`. which indicates that python thinks that the module is already loaded, just that it doesn't contain `C`. That's what the question is about.

Comment: On p3.6 I got ImportError on the same problem set!

Comment: The loading seems different between python versions. Which one are you using?

Comment: 3.5.3. I don't think it should be different

Comment: Python changlog, Python 3.6.0 beta2: bpo-21578: Fixed misleading error message when ImportError called with invalid keyword args.

Comment: nope, I don't think that's it. that changelog record is about some `ImportError does not take keyword arguments` stuff

Comment: One thing is what they write in changelog, another is what implications the change has :) I believe it actually changed this circular reference error from AttributeError to ImportError. Why I do so? Because I tried the same code you provided on 3.6.0 and I got ImportError. Also there is no other patch touching ImportError. What is the most important here is - it is a circular reference and you should just accept it as an answer :)