# error importing files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

i have two modules Book Class and Author Class .The author class module imports the book class module as follows

```
from BookClass import Book
from PersonClass import Person

class Author(Person):
```

and the book class module also imports the author class module as follows

```
from AuthorClass import Author

class Book:
```

when i run any of the two modules it gives me an import error.I am not sure of how to fix this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to do cyclic imports which is the reason for the error.

Comment: this can help  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634342/circular-imports-and-class-fields-in-python3'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: @Kallz i tried the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634342/circular-imports-and-class-fields-in-python3' but it didn't work .I am not sure but i think this is not the same case as mine because he doesn't have two classes which are mutually dependent on each other as in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your book class module says

```
from AuthorClass import Author
```

Remember that `import` is an executable statement. When the interpreter executes that statement, the first thing it does is import this code:

```
from BookClass import Book
```

but at that moment the class `Book` isn't defined yet, because the definition of `Book` comes *after* `from AuthorClass import Author`.

You have two classes with mutual references, and I take it you have complete control over the module structure. If I were in that position I would make the problem go away by putting both class definitions in the same module.

Comment: Putting them in the same module worked fine.But i wanted to separate them in different modules as a sort of organization.

Comment: I realize that| and in principle it's a good approach. But in a dynamic language, it doesn't work well if you have two classes that refer to each other.